# 'ls' output timestamps different for "old" files in /tmp versus in home directory

Tags: linux, networking, nfs, timestamps

I'm ssh'd into my university Linux servers (RHEL 7). My question has to do with 'ls' and "old" files.

Home directory:

```
$ touch -d '1918-11-11 11:00 GMT' wwi-armistice
$ touch now
$ sleep 1
$ touch now1
$ TZ=UTC0 ls -lt --full-time wwi-armistice now now1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2054-12-17 17:28:16.000000000 +0000 wwi-armistice
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2018-05-04 22:07:10.743637000 +0000 now1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2018-05-04 22:06:59.992632000 +0000 now
```

tmp directory:

```
$ tmp=$(mktemp -d)
$ cd $tmp
$ touch -d '1918-11-11 11:00 GMT' wwi-armistice
$ touch now
$ sleep 1
$ touch now1
$ TZ=UTC0 ls -lt --full-time wwi-armistice now now1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2018-05-04 23:04:27.031485854 +0000 now1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2018-05-04 23:04:22.907373125 +0000 now
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 1918-11-11 11:00:00.000000000 +0000 wwi-armistice
```

I know the reason the first output shows wwi-armistice in 2054 has something to do with signed 32-bit to unsigned 32-bit conversion of Unix time. If someone could confirm that and perhaps explain why (something to do with network?), that would be great.

My second, bigger question is: Why is wwi-armistice listed correctly when I do the example in /tmp?

Comment: I would guess example 1 directory is in a remote NFS server of 32 bits and the  system is 64 bits, but I could be saying a very stupid thing.

Answer (score 0):

The OS you are running is not enough to identify the root cause of the behavior difference. What also matters is the file system used to store the file access and modification time.

As you guessed, the wrong 2054-12-17 date is due to the target date being written as an unsigned 32-bit integer but read as a signed 32-bit integer.

- `1918-11-11 11:00:00` = `1541934000` seconds after 32-bit minimal unsigned time (`1901-12-13 08:45:52`)
- `2054-12-17 17:28:16` = `1541934000` seconds after 32-bit maximal signed time (`2038-01-19 03:14:16`)

Your home directory is likely stored either on NFSv3 or on a local file system that stores these dates on 32 bit.

On the other hand, `/tmp` is backed by `tmpfs`, `ext4` or whatever file system that stores dates on 64 bit so is immune to the issue.